# Why does my click event not fire when I add each blocks into my template to iterate through a collection (Meteor)

Tags: meteor

The event fires only when I remove the each blocks. What the event does is apply a vertical accordion slide down transition on an element. What I want to do is add the same slide down transition to all my documents when they are displayed in my views.

Right now, when I add an each block to iterate through my collection and display all the documents from my collection, the slide down event stops working.

Here's my template:

```
<template name="auctionsList">


   <div class="container">

       <div id='cssmenu'>

           <ul> 
            {{#each auctions}}
                {{>auction}}
            {{/each}}
           </ul>          

        </div> <!-- end cssmenu -->

   </div><!-- end container -->

      {{#if isReady}}
          {{#if hasMoreauctions}}
              <a class="load-more btn btn-default center-block text-uppercase" id="loadMore" href="#" style="margin-top:10px;">Load More</a>
          {{/if}}
      {{else}}
          <div class="loading">{{>spinner}}</div>
      {{/if}}
  </template>



  <template name="auction">
     <li class='has-sub'>     
        <a href='#'>      
            <div class="auction-image">
                <img src="brand_logos/DominosPizza.png" class="img-responsive" height="200" width="200">
            </div>


            {{> durationLeft}}         
        </a>


        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'>
            <span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
        </ul>

     </li>           
  </template>
```

Here's my rendered/helper

```
Template.auctionsList.rendered = function () {  


                    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){


                    $(this).removeAttr('href');
                    var element = $(this).parent('li');
                    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
                        element.removeClass('open');
                        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
                        element.find('ul').slideUp();
                    }
                    else {
                        element.addClass('open');
                        element.children('ul').slideDown();
                        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
                        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
                        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
                        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
                    }


                });
            }

Template.auctionsList.helpers({

                auctions: function () {
                    return Template.instance().userauctions();
                }
  });


Template.auctionsList.events({
'click #cssmenu li.has-sub>a' : function(event, template) {
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp();
    }
    else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown();
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
    }


}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move this from rendered to events. `$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){ }`

Answer (score 0):

Put the event within the auction template where your `<li>` tag exists.

**Updated**

Couple of things based on the gists you published:

1) you should try not use script tags directly in the template - i havent seen this often if at all. Move all this code to

```
Template.accordion.rendered = function(){ //here };
```

or better make it work in auctionsList because then its not duplicated x times for every each iteration.

But what would be even better is not to have the 'on' event at all. You should use a meteor event... like you mentioned in your earlier post. Meteor events have access to 'this' which is the current context item.

I would try put it in a template event on the master auctionsList template and later on worry about how it will work with the sub templates.

2) I dont think you need to add everything into another template like you have, the accordion template doesnt really need to exist, you can probably get away with putting it in the auction template (consider using even auctions to do the click event because if you do it that way your js snippet wont be repeated x times per post listing.You only need this once..

3) When you create the li in the auction template give it an ID at that point

```
<li id={{new accordion code in auction template}}>
```

You can then reference this id on your template click event. If you are new to meteor do yourself a favor and do the following in a click event to better understand what is going on (you will most likely find the ID you need within one of the values - most likely this:

```
Template.YourTemplate.events({
    'click any button in your each': function(event,bl,value)
    {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(bl);
        console.log(value);
        //and most importantly
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

I know its not "an answer" but i hope it leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok so the event that's in my Template.auctionsList.rendered = function () {  } 
block, I put in my li tags , right. I wrapped them in script tags. I go and check and click on an element and the event does fire! However it fires way too many times. Like the event is supposed to make the element slide down content , however now with your advice the element keeps sliding down back and forth. Like 2 or 3 times.

Comment: Oh I know what's going on the slide down transition is looping as well. So when i click on the first document in my view . it slides down 5 times because there are 5 documents in my collection. So for example if I remove all the documents and just leave one , the slide down transition will slide down once. But this is not all I want , i want the one slide down transition to fire just once for every document I add to my collection.

Comment: create a template helper that gives it a unique ID then you can use this in your event.

Comment: Hey I got it to work but I'm not sure if its very clean?

Comment: Here's a couple of links
the event template with helpers
https://gist.github.com/ecuanaso/c514070e9cd984478319

the auction template
https://gist.github.com/ecuanaso/05106f817a0a286a52fb

Comment: @ecuanaso I say if it works its generally okay, as long as you are not going to list 100 items at a time then so be it, from a learning perspective see my updated comment. hope it helps!